# Sql Not IN and Not Exists Clauses are not working with Where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get Items which were sold before a given date plus Items which are never sold.
So, Using below queries i get Items which were sold before a given date but i don't get Items which were never sold.

When i separately execute `NOT IN` and `NOT EXIST` Queries i get Items in result that don't exist in `ItemsSold` table. What's wrong here ?

**Full Query with NOT EXISTS**

```
select MAx(ITM.Name) as Name,Max(ITM.ItemID) as ID,Max(ItemsSold.UpdatedDate) as LastSaleDate from Items ITM
Inner join ItemsSold on ItemsSold.ItemID = ITM.ItemID
where convert(varchar,ItemsSold.UpdatedDate,111) < '2019/04/01'
or  NOT EXISTS (select ItemsSold.ItemID from ItemsSold where ItemsSold.ItemID=ITM.ItemID) 
Group by ITM.ItemID order by ITM.ItemID;
```

**Full Query with NOT IN**

```
select MAx(ITM.Name) as Name,Max(ITM.ItemID) as ID,Max(ItemsSold.UpdatedDate) as LastSaleDate from Items ITM
Inner join ItemsSold on ItemsSold.ItemID = ITM.ItemID
where convert(varchar,ItemsSold.UpdatedDate,111) < '2019/04/01'
or ITM.ItemID NOT IN (select ItemsSold.ItemID from ItemsSold) 
Group by ITM.ItemID order by ITM.ItemID
```

**NOT IN separately**

```
select Items.Name,Items.ItemID from Items where Items.ItemID NOT IN (select ItemsSold.ItemID from ItemsSold) order by ItemID
```

Executing NOT IN and NOT EXISTS Query separately does return actual correct data but with full query it doesn't.

Comment: Do you mean `AND` not `OR`? Also, you forgot to declare your `varchar` lengths. But *WHY* are you converting the value at all, leave it as a `date`; you're ruining tmyour query's performance doing that.

Comment: I dont know about varchar length defining cuz it always work like this when comparing dates in this case it's also working.

Comment: i mean OR .. because i want to get items that were sold before given data also items which were never sold (not exists in ItemsSold table)

Comment: Wait, why are you even doing a`EXISTS`,. You `INMRR JOIN` to that table, so it is impossible for roes to be returned a a row not be in the table `ItemsSold`; we need sample data here that replicates the "problem" and expected results.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should do it. Drop that `CONVERT` to a `varchar`, it makes the query non SARGABLE, and use proper date logic. And you should also always declare your length, scale and precision and not doing so will result in unexpected results.

Comment: Using inner join i am getting items that exist in `ItemsSold` table using date caparison . to get items that doesn't exist i am using Exists or Not in

Comment: So you want a list of items sold that weren't sold..? Well that would be 0 rows then. If something was sold, it can't be not sold, and vice versa; so this is working as "intended"?

Comment: No ! i want a list of items that were sold before a given date plus items that were never sold .

Comment: I am not pro specially in SQL . Ill be really happy and thankful if you can help me here also explanation of what you said about date logic Sir .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no sample data or expected results this is a guess, however, based purely on your existing SQL and your comment *"No ! i want a list of items that were sold before a given date plus items that were never sold ."* this might be what you are after:

```
SELECT I.ItemID
FROM Items I
     LEFT JOIN ItemsSold ItS ON I.ItemID = ItS.ItemID
GROUP BY I.ItemID
HAVING MAX(ItS.UpdatedDate) < '20190401' --Proper date logic, got rid of CONVERT
    OR MAX(ItS.ItemID) IS NULL;
```

It might be that you want `MIN(ItS.UpdatedDate)`, depending on if you want items that were *only* sold before `2019-04-01` or if you want items that were at least first sold **before** `2019-04-01` (impossible to know from the lack of description).

If not, I refer to my prior comment *"we need sample data here that replicates the "problem" and expected results."*.

Comment: and i want Items that were ONLY SOLD before .. so should i use `MIN` instead ?

Comment: and for the date logic. ill be passing date from `C#` application so will your approach work then ?

Comment: If your passing from C# you should be replacing the value with a parameter and be using `Parameters.Add`.

Comment: I know that. and what about min ? should i use MIn if i want only Items before ?

Comment: And hey ! Date has no affect on result ! i mean i always get same amount of items ..

Comment: No, you want `MAX`.

Comment: Probably because none were purchased after April. Can't tell you more; we never got that sample data I asked for.

Comment: Also, as a courtesy, please don't shout(!), @RaoHammasHussain. There is no need for it. Thanks. 

Comment: oh I am really really sorry if my writing style gave shouting impression. I am actually extremely thankful that you came and help me .I had zero intention of shouting.. I just use ! when telling some information or fact.. But still sorry 

Comment: From Wikipedia: *'usually used after an interjection or exclamation to indicate strong feelings or high volume (shouting), or to show emphasis, and often marks the end of a sentence, for example: "Watch out!"'* if you're telling someone a fact you shouldn't be shouting it at them; that will be seen as rude @RaoHammasHussain. Only time I really find I ever use an ! on SO is when someone has some very dangerous code (such as being wide open to injection), where I might might say something like "Stop, don't write your SQL like this! This is wide open to injection and ..." Which shows the severity

Comment: But SO isn't a place to talk English; I'm just letting you know (here) that misuse of a ! could be seen as rude and may get negative responses from users. 

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want items that were *only* sold before a certain date or never sold.  That is, no items were sold later:

Use `not exists`:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from itemssold its
                  where its.ItemId = i.ItemId and
                        its.UpdatedDate >= '2019-04-01'
                 );
```

You want appropriate indexes no matter how you phrased the query if performance is a consideration.  For this, the index would be on `itemssold(ItemId, UpdatedDate)`.  This should be much faster than the an aggregation form of the query.

If the question is more how it is phrased:  There exists an order before the date or no orders at all, then you would use two comparisons:

```
select i.*
from items i
where exists (select 1
              from itemssold its
              where its.ItemId = i.ItemId and
                    its.UpdatedDate < '2019-04-01'
             ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from itemssold its
                  where its.ItemId = i.ItemId
                 );
```